# Any ideas howto increase speed of selecting elements from a large list of string

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a large list of strings(1 million elements). Just for example:

```
largeList = ['abc','def','ghi','kkl_year12_month12']
```

I have to extract the string elements which share the following items:

```
criteria_1 = ['year12', 'year14'] ##in my real case they are 2 thousands.

criteria_2 = 'month12'  ##in my real case it is just one.
```

I did as follows:

```
answer = [x for x in largeList if any(y in x for y in criteria_1) and 'month12' in x]
```

But my method is extremely slow.

Any ideas to increase the speed?

Comment: Maybe filter the `largeList` first by `criteria_2` and the check for `criteria_1`, if `criteria_2` reduces the list size considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers suggest to check first for the second criteria (because it is the most simple and therefore quickest check). This can also be done by changing the order of the criteria around the `and` keyword:

```
answer = [x for x in largeList if 'month12' in x and any(y in x for y in criteria_1)]
```

if `'month12 in x'` yields false the second criteria `any(y in x for y in criteria_1)` will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many elements will be filtered by `criteria_2` filtering you largeList first might improve speed.

```
>>> def find1(largelist1,crit1,crit2):
>>>    return  [x for x in largeList if any(y in x for y in crit1) and crit2 in x]

>>> def find2(largelist1,crit1,crit2):
>>>         filt_l = (x for x in largelist1 if crit2 in x)
>>>         return [x for x in filt_l if any(y in x for y in crit1)]


>>> %timeit find1(largeList,criteria_1,criteria_2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.18 µs per loop
>>> %timeit find2(largeList,criteria_1,criteria_2)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 µs per loop
```

additionally it might help to use numpys arrays.